# Regular expression in batch file is not working

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, findstr

we used Regex in batch by using following command,

```
Dir "C:\Test\Res345_45664_1335" /s /b /a:-d | findstr /R "[(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)]" > filelist.txt
```

The "C:\Test\Res345_45664_1335" directory contains following files,

```
Res345_45664_1335.txt
Output.txt
list.txt
```

We need file that’s in the format 
But the above dir command with regex displaying all files present in the "C:\Test\Res345_45664_1335" directory. Because "C:\Test\Res345_45664_1335" directory contains the same format "Res345_45664_1335". But We need files only(with full path).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`\d`, `()`  and `+`  are not a valid meta characters in `findstr`.   See `findstr  /?`  fore more advanced help. You should substitute it with `[0-9][0-9]*` .

```
Dir "C:\Test\Res345_45664_1335" /s /b /a:-d | findstr /ER "[0-9][0-9]*_[0-9][0-9]*_[0-9][0-9]*.txt" > filelist.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the files have extensions?

```
Dir "c:\test\Res345_45664_1335" /s /b /a:-d | findstr /R "[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*\."
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Dir /s /b /a:-d *_*_*
```

Not really sure what you mean by "the format"

---

Ah - filename in format string_string_string...

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b /a-d *_*_*') DO ECHO "%%~ni"|FINDSTR /r "..*_..*_..*" >nul&IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO %%i
```

(that's as a batch line - reduce `%%` to `%` to run from the prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Batch scripting does not have such feasibility as like programming languages. Some simple regular expression can be worked with 'findstr' but it has some limitations like '+' character has replacement as '.*'. But don't worry, I have a solution for you.

you can simply use power-shell inside a batch script and here below your solution:

```
@powershell -command "if (($string -match $regex) -eq $true) {write-host matched!}"
```

It will work for you and if you want to throw an exception then simply throw and assert in batch script as:

```
@powershell -command "if (($string -match $regex) -eq $true) {throw [System.ArgumentException] invalid input}"
```

I hope this would suffice for you and others who may in need of this.